# How to extend element width both ways?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, width, drag

Does that title sound confusing? I thought it might well anyways.

When I person clicks on the page I want them to be able to me a little line shorter and long.

You can see what I mean here:

http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/HKLhE/9/show/

Do a Mousedown and them move your move to the right. It works fine. 
But now, move you mouse to the left. See the problem? It goes the same direction as it did when you dragged to the right. I know this is because i'm using width and obviously width on goes one way.

This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dragStatus = 0,
        getPos, giveRandomID;
    $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
        dragStatus = 0;
        getPos = {
            top: event.clientY,
            left: event.clientX
        };
        giveRandomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        var line = $('#line' + giveRandomID);
        if (dragStatus == 0) {
            $('body').append("<div id='line" + giveRandomID + "' class='line' style='position:absolute;top:" + getPos.top + "px;left:" + getPos.left + "px;background:black;width:2px;height:5px'></div>");
            dragStatus = 1;
        }
        if (dragStatus == 1) {
            if (event.clientX > line.offset().left) {
                line.css({
                    width: event.clientX - line.offset().left
                });
            } else {
                line.css({
                    width: line.offset().left - event.clientX
                });
            }
            //for DEG  "-" Top-Math.abs(DEG*2) for Deg "+" Top+(DEG*2)
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragStatus = 2;
    });
});​
```

I hope someone can help me out with this. Maybe a complete different way to set this up. Just something to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the line stretch to the left, you have to update the `left` property:

```
        if (event.clientX > getPos.left) {
            line.css({
                left: getPos.left,
                width: event.clientX - getPos.left
            });
        } else {
            line.css({
                left: event.clientX,
                width: getPos.left - event.clientX
            });
        }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HKLhE/16/

Comment: Also, you should initialize `dragStatus` to 2 to avoid the JavaScript errors appearing in the console before the first line is drawn (actually, you may not need `dragStatus` at all - you can just check `getPos` and check whether the line exists), and there's probably no need to set the `left` of the line when creating it this way (since it will be set immediately afterward).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the `else` case (moving right) to set the `left` property to `auto` and the `right` property to the initial mouse click X position. Comparing to the `offset().left` when moving left won't work because that value is changing.

Try this out for size:

http://jsfiddle.net/HKLhE/20/

Edit: Brilliand's solution is much more elegant.